# research on brain-eating amoeba

Tags: microbiology, invertebrates

Are there any alternative treatments for brain-eating amoeba?

I've spent about 6 hours trying to find information about this and haven't had any success.

Comment: Sorry, this is a science list. We don't do "alternative medicine", nor can we recommend research projects to students. This is a site for questions about biological processes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for recommendations for research topics, and not about biology.

Comment: This is off-topic indeed but to foster interest, intravenous amphotericin B and rifampicin was used with varying success. Miltefosine has shown efficacy. In almost all cases the infections are fatal without intervention or luck, however.

Answer (score 0):

*Naegleria fowleri* & other protozoa like *Acanthamoeba castellani* are sometimes referred to as "brain-eating" amoebas. The latter due to the severity of the disease they can cause and the remarkable inefficiency of the treatments administered at the moment of diagnosis. If you wanna know more about this I would suggest reading this paper
https://aac.asm.org/content/aac/59/11/6677.full.pdf

Although if you are a beginner in the field of microbiology you will probably have trouble understanding a paper like that. If this is the case I would suggest reading the introductory chapters of a general medical microbiology book first. The one I started with was Murray's Medical Microbiology from elsevier saunders; I know there is a spanish edition (which is what I read) as well if you happen to prefer that instead of english.